# Error with \titleformat command after inserting TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, titlesec, tocloft, titletoc

## MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsbsy,amsmath}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{titlesec, titleps titletoc}

%%\titleformat{command}[shape]{format}{label}{sep}{before-code}[after-code]
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalsize \rmfamily}{\theparagraph.}{1em}{}[]
\titleformat{\section}{\centering\normalsize}{ARTICLE \thesection}{1em}{\uppercase} %
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\normalsize \rmfamily}{Section \thesubsection.}{1em}{\underline}[. \;]
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]{\normalsize \rmfamily}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}[]

\renewcommand\cftsecfont{ARTICLE \uppercase}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecfont{Section }

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents % Breaks at this line

\section{Defined terms; rules of construction}
\section{Organization of partnership}
\subsection{Formation}
\subsection{Name}
\subsection{Certificates and licenses}
\subsubsection{Optional}

\end{document}
```

## MWE output (using overleaf):

[image]

## Notes:

Based on compile errors, the problem lies here I believe. Something to do with missing {}s.

```
\titleformat{\section}{\centering\normalsize}{ARTICLE \thesection}{1em}{\uppercase} %
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\normalsize \rmfamily}{Section \thesubsection.}{1em}{\underline}[. \;]
```

## Desired output (using overleaf):

Which I achieve unless I try inserting a TOC. Overleaf allows you to view this output with compile errors. But attempting to export to PDF via LyX you get: `There was an error opening this document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired`.

[image]

Comment: \usepackage{titlesec, titleps titletoc} ---> \usepackage{titlesec, titleps, titletoc}

Comment: @flav nice catch, thanks! unfortunately, i'm still getting those compile errors. "! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \hbox 
l.2 ...mberline {2}Organization of partnership}{1}"

Comment: with pdflatex it's work fine ; how do you compile ?

Comment: my apologies, maybe try compiling again after uncommenting \tableofcontents? I have it commented in my MWE, i'll fix that

Comment: Try loading `\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}`,  not `\usepackage{titleps,titleps}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @flav and @Bernard, you two were correct to note that that was an issue. I also found that I messed up the structure of the `\titleformat` command which I figured out upon re-reading the `titlesec` package PDF: `\titleformat{command}[shape]{format}{label}{sep}{before-code}[after-code]`

## The MWE solution that should create the first image without any compile errors:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsbsy,amsmath}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{titlesec, titleps, titletoc}

%%\titleformat{command}[shape]{format}{label}{sep}{before-code}[after-code]
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalsize}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}[] %
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\centering\normalsize} 
{ARTICLE\space\thesection}{1em}{\uppercase}[] %
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\normalsize}{Section\space\thesubsection}{1em}{\underline}[.\;] %
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]{\normalsize}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{\underline}[.\;] %

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{ARTICLE \uppercase}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecfont{Section }

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Defined terms; rules of construction}
\section{Organization of partnership}
\subsection{Formation}
\subsection{Name}
\subsection{Certificates and licenses}
\subsubsection{Optional}

\end{document}
```